# Unable to install nodemon globally through terminal, showing an error

Tags: nodemon

If I give as `npm install -g nodemon`
getting an error as :

```
checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
```

Please any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need root permissions: try with

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission error and you can use **sudo**, But Running `sudo npm install` (without -g) will create a local directory that can only be altered by the root user. This can really screw things up for you if you try to do `npm <something>` in the same directory or project later on.

Even `sudo npm install -g` with a valid installation target can mess things up for you and make it hard to use npm without sudo under some circumstances in the future particularly if you change your npm configuration midstream.
you can use the following steps to update your local OS:

1. Set your prefix for global installs, e.g. `npm config set prefix ~/.npm`
2. Update your PATH to include `~/.npm/bin`. For example: `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` if you’re using zsh.

See [Don’t Use sudo with npm](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92) for more information.